# Background process/task in genexus?

Tags: genexus

We're using Genexus EV3 to develop a project and we noticed that we can use it to easily alert users through SMS or emails about relevant information.

I'd like to know if it's possible to create some sort of background process in genexus that checks a database and so that we can send emails based on the information present in the database.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a asynchronous call to a procedure object using the `submit` method, like:

```
// Some code...
prAnyProcedure.submit(&parm1, &parm2)
// Some code...
// Some code...
```

In this case, the main program flow will continue processing immediately.

But if you need to call a procedure from time to time without any user intervention, you should use a server-side tool like ant or the cron/crontab linux utility.

http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#what-is-ant

http://linux.die.net/man/8/cron

Comment: Consider that `submit` takes a first blank parameter, eg: `prAnyProcedure.submit('', &parm1, &parm2)`

Comment: Indeed what I need is to call the procedure periodically. I was told that using a scheduler to run a procedure's executable was what should be done, but it seems to me that Genexus should feature something like this already. This doesn't seem very deployment friendly... I'd need to setup the scheduler on every machine the project is deployed into.

Answer (score 2):

I made some like you need.
I made a procedure, make it MAIN and are launched with de squeduler task (it run every day at 9am). In a table I have the reminder and the mail addresses, the massage to sent etc. This is the main procedure

```
for each empresa
    where EmpresaEstado=1
    &Empresanombre=EmpresaNombre
    &EmpresaEmail=EmpresaEmail
    &EmpresaServidorSalida=EmpresaServidorSalida
    &EmpresaServidorPassword=EmpresaServidorPassword
endfor

for each recordatorios

    where RecordatoriosEstado=1
    where RecordatoriosDiaEnvio=day(today())
        &smtp.Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
        &smtp.Port = 25
        &smtp.Sender.Address = TRIM(&EmpresaEmail)
        &smtp.Sender.Name = TRIM(&empresanombre)
        &smtp.Authentication = 1
        &smtp.Secure=1
        &smtp.UserName = TRIM(&empresaEmail)
        &smtp.Password = trim(&EmpresaServidorPassword)
        &recordatoriosasunto=RecordatoriosAsunto
        &recordatoriostexto=RecordatoriosTexto

        &mail.To.New('Mauricio','mlopez.informatica@gmail.com')
        &smtp.ErrDisplay = 0
        &smtp.Login()
        for each
            where RecordatoriosClienteEstado=1
            &mail.BCC.new(RecordatoriosClienteMail1,trim(RecordatoriosClienteMail1))
            if RecordatoriosClienteMail2<>''
                &mail.BCC.new(RecordatoriosClienteMail2,trim(RecordatoriosClienteMail2))
            endif
        endfor
        &mail.Subject = &recordatoriosasunto
        &mail.Text = &recordatoriostexto
        &smtp.Send(&mail)
        &mail.Clear()
        &smtp.Logout()
endfor
```

Comment: consider adding details of your programming language and other that might be important

Comment: Is procedure made on Genexus Evo 3. The procedure is set as main program and run every day, launched by the windows scheduder task